# Determine $f(v)$ and $f(w)$ in the coordinate represention in $\mathbb{R}^3$ and the mapping matrix $M^{E_4}_{E_3}(f)$

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, matrix-calculus, change-of-basis

> Given is the linear mapping $f:\mathbb{R}^4\to \mathbb{R}^3$ with $$M_\mathcal{B}^\mathcal{A}(f)=\begin{pmatrix}4 & 0 & -4 & 2 \\ 0 & 2 & 4 & 2 \\ -2 & 0 & 0 & -2 \end{pmatrix}$$ with respect to the bases $$\mathcal{A}=(\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix} 0\\ 1  \\ 1 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ -1 \end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ -1 \\ 1 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix})\quad \mathcal{B}=(\begin{pmatrix} 1\\1\\1 \end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix} 1\\0\\1 \end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix} 1\\2\\2 \end{pmatrix}$$
>
> a) The vectors $v=\begin{pmatrix} 2\\2\\-2\\2 \end{pmatrix}$ and $w=\begin{pmatrix} -1\\1\\0\\1 \end{pmatrix}$ are given. Using the matrix $M^\mathcal{A}_\mathcal{B}(f)$, determine the vectors $f(v)$ and $f(w)$ in the coordinate representation with respect to the standard basis of $\mathbb{R}^3$.
>
> b) Let $E_4$ and $E_3$ be the standard bases of $\mathbb{R}^4$ and $\mathbb{R}^3$, respectively. Determine the mapping matrix $M^{E_4}_{E_3}(f)$ and check your previously calculated results with the matrix.

---

Can you give me hints on how to solve the two tasks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For (a), just compute $[v]_{\mathcal{A}}$ and $[w]_{\mathcal{A}}$ (the coordinate vectors of $v$ and $w$ respect to the basis $\mathcal{A}$). Then
$$[f(v)]_{\mathcal{B}}=\textsf{M}_{\mathcal{B}}^{\mathcal{A}}(f)[v]_{\mathcal{A}}$$
and similarly
$$[f(w)]_{\mathcal{B}}=\textsf{M}_{\mathcal{B}}^{\mathcal{A}}(f)[w]_{\mathcal{A}}$$
For example, for $v$ we have
$$v=\begin{pmatrix}2\\2\\-2\\2\end{pmatrix}=2\begin{pmatrix}1\\0\\0\\1\end{pmatrix}+0\begin{pmatrix}0\\1\\1\\0\end{pmatrix}+0\begin{pmatrix}1\\0\\0\\-1\end{pmatrix}-2\begin{pmatrix}0\\-1\\1\\0\end{pmatrix}$$
hence
$$[v]_\mathcal{A}=\begin{pmatrix}2\\0\\0\\-2\end{pmatrix}$$
and then
$$[f(u)]_\mathcal{B}=\begin{pmatrix}4&0&-4&2\\0&2&4&2\\-2&0&0&-2\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}2\\0\\0\\-2\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}4\\-4\\0\end{pmatrix}$$
Therefore
$$f(u)=4\begin{pmatrix}1\\1\\1\end{pmatrix}-4\begin{pmatrix}1\\0\\1\end{pmatrix}+0\begin{pmatrix}1\\2\\2\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}0\\4\\0\end{pmatrix}$$
Can you continue?

Comment: Just pick the coefficients in the linear combination.

Comment: Yeah, I made a typo thanks.

Comment: $[w]_A=\begin{pmatrix} 0\\ \frac12\\ -1 \\ \frac{-1}{2} \end{pmatrix}$

Comment: And $[f(u)]_B=\begin{pmatrix}3\\-4\\1\end{pmatrix}$ Is that right?

Comment: Everything is correct. Although it would be $[f(w)]_\mathcal{B}$ instead of $u$.

Comment: Alright, thanks for clarification!

Answer (score 1):

For a more systematic approach:

> $$
> M^{E_4}_{E_3}(f)=M^{E_4}_{E_3}(id\circ f\circ id)=M^{B}_{E_3}(id)\cdot M^{A}_{B}(f)\cdot M^{E_4}_{A}(id)\\=M^{B}_{E_3}(id)\cdot M^{A}_{B}(f)\cdot (M^{A}_{E_4}(id))^{-1}
> $$

Now $M^{B}_{E_3}(id)$, $M^{A}_{E_4}(id)$ and $M^{A}_{B}(f)$ are already given so you can happily compute $M^{E_4}_{E_3}(f)$ and  $[f(u)]_{E_3}=M^{E_4}_{E_3}(f)\cdot [u]_{E_4}$.

Comment: Is $M^B_{E_3}=\begin{pmatrix} 1&1&1\\1&0&2\\1&1&2 \end{pmatrix}$?

Comment: Yes,  this is correct.

Comment: Do I need to compute $\begin{pmatrix} 1&1&1\\1&0&2\\1&1&2 \end{pmatrix}\cdot\begin{pmatrix} 4&0&-4&2\\0&2&4&2\\-2&0&0 &-2\end{pmatrix}\cdot \begin{pmatrix} \frac12&0&0&\frac12\\0&\frac12&\frac12&0\\\frac12&0&0&\frac{-1}{2}\\0&\frac{-1}{2}&\frac12&0 \end{pmatrix}$?

Comment: Well that doesn't work. What have I done wrong?

Comment: You did nothing wrong so far.  I got $(0,4,0)$ after applying the vector $v=(2,2,-2,2)$ to the resulting matrix. Do you agree?

Comment: Oh ok, I mixed the positions that's why it didn't worked out. Yeah, I've got the same vector and for w I got $(3,-1,4)$

Comment: $M^{E_4}_{E_3}=\begin{pmatrix}1&0&2&1\\ -2&1&-1&2\\ 0&1&1&0\end{pmatrix}$

Comment: Everything correct?

Comment: $M^{E_4}_{E_3}(f)$ is correct but your result for $w$ is not.

Comment: Ok thank you, I will have a look at it in some minutes.

Comment: Its $(0,5,1)$ right?

Comment: Yes now everything is correct!